# How should I handle UUID fields using mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, uuid, mgo

I have this Document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ad0873b169ade0001345d34"
    },
    "j": {
        "$uuid": "94482b86-1005-e3a0-5235-55fb7c1d648a"
    },
    "v": "sign",
    "d": "a",
    "s": "init",
    "response": {},
    "creation_date": {
        "$date": "2018-04-13T10:32:27.140Z"
    }
}
```

I want to filter & fetch some documents in Golang using mgo, and here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type JOB struct {
   ID               bson.ObjectId       `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Key          string              `bson:"j"`
   Svc              string              `bson:"v"`
   DocType          string              `bson:"d"`
   Status           string              `bson:"s"`
   CreationDate     time.Time           `bson:"creation_date"`
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://...")
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    c := session.DB("main").C("job")

    var results []JOB
    e := c.Find(bson.M{"v": "sign"}).All(&results)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    for _, job := range results[:5] {
        fmt.Println(job.ID, job.Key, job.Svc, job.DocType, job.Status, job.CreationDate)

    }

}
```

Here's the output when I run my program:

```
ObjectIdHex("5acf91e0269c650001a82683")  sign a ok 2018-04-12 19:05:36.294 +0200 CEST
ObjectIdHex("5ad0873b169ade0001345d34")  sign a init 2018-04-13 12:32:27.14 +0200 CEST
ObjectIdHex("5ad0873e169ade0001345d36")  sign a init 2018-04-13 12:32:30.852 +0200 CEST
ObjectIdHex("5ad08742169ade0001345d38")  sign a init 2018-04-13 12:32:34.478 +0200 CEST
ObjectIdHex("5ad087492e083b00013a862a")  sign a init 2018-04-13 12:32:41.577 +0200 CEST
```

**Problem**:

`job.Key` (`j` field in MongoDB Document which is a uuid) remains empty. I've tried also `"github.com/satori/go.uuid"` but I couldn't figure it out.

So I would like to know how to handle that uuid field, and more generally how to debug this problem. Complete newbie in Go.

For example in python I could get a Document and using `doc._data` I could see all fields of that document, is there a equivalent way of doing this in Go?

**UPDATE**

I tried to set Key as `bson.Raw`, I see some bytes, but cannot convert them to uuid:

```
fmt.Println(job.Key)
u := uuid.FromBytesOrNil(job.Key.Data)
fmt.Println(u)
```

Output:

```
{5 [16 0 0 0 3 160 227 5 16 134 43 72 148 138 100 29 124 251 85 53 82]}
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas I've figured out that I'm getting bin data with `0x05` Kind.

So I changed `Job` struct to:

```
Key             bson.Binary         `bson:"j"`
```

and after doing query, I unmarshal that binary data like this:

```
import "github.com/satori/go.uuid"

var Ids []uuid.UUID

for _, job := range results {
    u, err := uuid.FromBytes(job.Key.Data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Ids = append(Ids, u)
}
```

So now in `Job.Key.Data` I have binary version of UUID according to [this](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/3f83fa5005286a7fe593b055f0d7771a7dce4655/bson/bson.go#L416) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `satori/go.uuid` lib you mentioned, you can accomplish this by implementing the 
[bson.Setter](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2/bson/bson.go#L94) interface on the type you use for the UUID field.

```
type Setter interface {
    SetBSON(raw Raw) error
}
```

A minimal example could look like the following. First I define my struct, but instead of the UUID type from satori/go.uuid I instead embed that type into my own type. This allows us to define a method on it. You could also accomplish this with different type declaration such as `type MyUUID uuid.UUID` but then you would need to perform a type conversion `uuid.UUID(record.UUID)` to gain access to the fields and methods on the underlying `uuid.UUID` type.

```
// MyUUID is a struct embedding the actual real UUID type
// so that we can implement bson.Setter
type MyUUID struct{ uuid.UUID }

// Record is a simplified version of what you're reading in
type Record struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    UUID MyUUID `bson:"j"`
}
```

Next we implement the `bson.Setter` method on `MyUUID`

```
// SetBSON lets us perform custom deserialization
func (m *MyUUID) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    // First we decode the BSON data as a anonymous J struct
    var j struct {
        UUID string `bson:"$uuid"`
    }
    err := raw.Unmarshal(&j)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Then we use the parse the string UUID
    uu, err := uuid.FromString(j.UUID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Finally build the result type and set it into the pointer to our record's field.
    *m = MyUUID{uu}

    return nil
}
```

It won't on the playground run due to the absence of packages, but fully functioning source that demonstrates this is available [here](https://play.golang.org/p/l8_0QhkrBMs). The example output when I run it locally:

```
> go run main.go
2018/06/16 14:49:49 {1 George {fdcfa79c-6b83-444e-9a91-a02f0aeaa260}}
2018/06/16 14:49:49 {1 George fdcfa79c-6b83-444e-9a91-a02f0aeaa260}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Your snippets works well but when I change my struct element type to `MyUUID` and print `job.Key` I still get `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` I'm not sure if it's help or not, but the `bson.Raw.Kind` I receive from mongo is `5` ...

Comment: I've changed `return nil` to `fmt.Println(err)` and I get: ```uuid: incorrect UUID length:
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
BSON kind 0x05 isn't compatible with type string```

Comment: That's because your document structure is defining the uuid string value as being in key `j` but it is actually in key `uuid` nested in key `j`.

Comment: @sheshkovsky I updated the answer to more specifically match your data format.

Comment: I still have the problem. Because in your snippet `raw.Kind` is 0x03 (embedded document) but when I run my code I see that `raw.Kind` is 0x05 (which is binary I guess). Is there a way to convert binary to embedded doc kind?

Comment: it seems to be a `md5` instead of uuid: https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/3f83fa5005286a7fe593b055f0d7771a7dce4655/bson/bson.go#L416

Answer (score 2):

I read @sheshkovsky and @Thomas ideas and I actually came out with a copy paste solution which in my case worked.

```
// MongoUUID represents a UUID as saved in MongoDB
type MongoUUID struct{ uuid.UUID }

// SetBSON implements the bson.Setter interface
func (id *MongoUUID) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    // First we decode the BSON data as a UUID Binary
    // Optionally we can check here if the Kind is correct
    var j bson.Binary
    err := raw.Unmarshal(&j)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Then we use the parse the string UUID
    uu, err := uuid.FromBytes(j.Data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Finally build the result type and set it into the pointer to our record's field.
    *id = MongoUUID{uu}

    return nil
}

// GetBSON implements the bson.Getter interface
func (id *MongoUUID) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    // we create an empty UUID Binary Mongo Object
    ret := bson.Binary{
        Kind: bson.BinaryUUID,
        Data: nil,
    }

    // And we pass the UUID data to it
    if id == nil {
        ret.Data = uuid.Nil.Bytes()
    } else {
        ret.Data = id.Bytes()
    }

    // finally we return ;)
    return ret, nil
}
```

With this solution you can directly pass a MongoUUID wrapping an uuid.UUID value like a charm :)