# UUID as _id error - can't use an array for _id

Tags: mongodb, go, uuid

I'm attempting to use UUIDs for my `_id` field in a MongoDB.

I have a wrapper struct to hold my record, like so:

```
type mongoWrapper struct {
    ID      uuid.UUID       `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`
    Payment storage.Payment `bson:"payment" json:"payment"`
}
```

This is my code around the InsertOne function from the MongoDB driver packages:

```
func (s *Storage) Create(newPayment storage.Payment) (uuid.UUID, error) {
    mongoInsert := wrap(newPayment)
    c := s.client.Database(thisDatabase).Collection(thisCollection)

    insertResult, errInsert := c.InsertOne(context.TODO(), mongoInsert)
    if errInsert != nil {
        return uuid.Nil, errInsert
    }

    fmt.Println("Inserted a single document: ", insertResult.InsertedID)

    return mongoInsert.ID, nil
}
```

This is my wrap() func that wraps up the payment record data, and takes an optional UUID argument or generates its own accordingly:

```
func wrap(p storage.Payment, i ...uuid.UUID) *mongoWrapper {
    mw := &mongoWrapper{ID: uuid.Nil, Payment: p}

    if len(i) > 0 {
        mw.ID = i[0]
        return mw
    }

    newID, errID := uuid.NewV4()
    if errID != nil {
        log.Fatal(errID)
    }

    mw.ID = newID

    return mw
}
```

When one of my tests calls Create() it returns the following error:

```
storage_test.go:38: err: multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{can't use an array for _id}]}, {<nil>}]
```

I'm using the following packages for my UUIDs and MongoDB driver:

```
import(
    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
)
```

I'm not clear on where exactly the problem lies.

Do I need some extra plumbing around the UUID in order for it to be handled correctly?

**edit:** I made some more changes, but the UUID still comes through as an array:

```
type mongoWrapper struct {
    UUID    mongoUUID       `bson:"uuid" json:"uuid"`
    Payment storage.Payment `bson:"payment" json:"payment"`
}

type mongoUUID struct {
    uuid.UUID
}

func (mu *mongoUUID) MarshalBSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(mu.UUID.String()), nil
}

func (mu *mongoUUID) UnmarshalBSON(b []byte) error {
    mu.UUID = uuid.FromStringOrNil(string(b))
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Related: [Performance gains to using UUID instead of its string representation as _id on MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327297/2313887) and [How should I handle UUID fields using mgo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50895446/2313887). It really comes down to personal choice, but I would strongly recommend the type actually be set as `bson.Binary`. Really comes down to whether the "textual" representation is important to you in queries or not, but since you opted for the "random" type, then I'm guessing an expected "text pattern" really isn't what you would be after.

Comment: Your marshaler is on a pointer, but you're using a concrete type, so the marshaler is being ignored. Either use `*mongoUUID` in your `mongoWrapper` struct, or change your marshaler to use `mongoUUID` as a receiver type.

Comment: I use concrete `mongoUUID` instead of pointers, and now I get ```storage_test.go:38: err: too few bytes to read next component```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the below implementation as a solution for this:

```
type mongoUUID struct {
    uuid.UUID
}

func (mu mongoUUID) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    return bsontype.Binary, bsoncore.AppendBinary(nil, 4, mu.UUID[:]), nil
}

func (mu *mongoUUID) UnmarshalBSONValue(t bsontype.Type, raw []byte) error {
    if t != bsontype.Binary {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid format on unmarshal bson value")
    }

    _, data, _, ok := bsoncore.ReadBinary(raw)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("not enough bytes to unmarshal bson value")
    }

    copy(mu.UUID[:], data)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped you out @saniales :)

Comment: This is a poor approach. It's much better to embed the type, as proposed in my answer, so that the methods on the embedded type are still usable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Flimzy - I've [refactored](https://github.com/jlucktay/rest-api/commit/caa8741b08c679115bbc7f25a5db79911cb921ff#diff-64e14639fdc8f8bdee63201031217aef) to embed the UUID type, and updated the answer as well

Answer (score 2):

[`uuid.UUID`](https://godoc.org/github.com/satori/go.uuid#UUID) is a `[16]byte` under the hood.

However, this type also implements the `encoding.TextMarshaler` interface, which I would expect mongo to honor (the same way the `json` package does).

I believe the solution is to create your own type, which embeds the `uuid.UUID` type, and provides a custom implementation of the [`bson.Marshaler` interface](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Marshaler).

Comment: I gave this a shot and edited the code changes into my question.

Comment: I came to [this implementation](https://github.com/jlucktay/rest-api/blob/970f6e80aa17df3390abca425c4d85edabc5ea83/pkg/storage/mongo/uuid.go) as a solution for this

Comment: Awesome @jlucktay please post this as answer. It works also for me.

Comment: @saniales: Neither my solution, nor jlucktay's use a type alias at all. And your proposal is identical to mine. So I'm not really sure what point you're making.